# Powershell: operation has been cancelled, after each shutdown/reboot

Tags: powershell, windows-registry, regedit

since the first time i tried to work with powershell, i faced this problem:
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSpxn.png)

i followed some steps to fix it, and it guided me to doing this:
deleting this directory `DisallowRun` from the regedit.
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BWh8.png)

when i delete this, i can run powershell properly and normally, but each time i reboot/shutdown my system, i have to do delete this directory again.
any help is appreciated.

Edit:

this is my personal computer at home, no one uses it but me. How can i fix that ?

Comment: That is being set by group policy so you are overriding your IT Department's settings. You should ask them for a change in policy. That said, I don't find myself using it much (if ever). I have either a prompt or an IDE open where I can run the file in question.

Comment: But this is my personal computer at home, no one uses it but me. How can i fix that ?

Comment: Open `gpedit.msc`. Navigate to `User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System`. Check if `Don't run specified Windows applications` is configured.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers it is not configured.

Comment: That was all I could find about it. If you wish to investigate further, I suggest you download procmon from sysinternals and have it monitor your registry writes. Filter on `DisallowRun` and enable boot logging in the options. You should be able to find what is writing the registry and draw conclusions (or next steps) from there.

Answer (score 0):

@Wassim : the answer could be more useful is you precise the context. Many people can help you, but give them some facts to help you.

The Computer is running  in a domain or a workgroup ? (ok, now we can presume that your computer run in a workgroup). 
What is the operating System ? The answer would be diffrent depending of the operating system.
Have you "Admin rights" on the computer ? 
The message seems to be clear : you haven't enough righ to do what you wan to do
and even if your account is local admin, do you know that to perform certain tasks you need elevation of privileges (runas admin). The only account without this behavior is the Builtin Administrator account

Oliv

Comment: This is my personal computer i used it at home, it is windows 10, i have admin rights.